# Regex to find the HTTP response code number

Tags: python, regex

I am a newbie to Regex. I was going through a problem where I needed to extract the HTTP response code given in the sample text. But I am not quite able to figure out the correct regex to apply re.findall.
My code below:

```
import os
import re
sample_text=['199.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/ 
 HTTP/1.0" 200 6245',
'unicomp6.unicomp.net - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/ 
HTTP/1.0" 200 3985',
'199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts- 
 73/mission-sts-73.html HTTP/1.0" 200 4085',
 'burger.letters.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400] "GET / 
shuttle/countdown/liftoff.html HTTP/1.0" 304 0',
 '199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/sts-73- 
patch-small.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 4179']

def func():
 r=str(sample_text)
 regext="(\s\d+)(?!.*\d$)"
 content_size=re.findall(regext,r)
 print(content_size)
```

The output should only extract the end number after HTTP such as 6245, 786 and 4085. But my code above included the status code 200 as well in the output. How do I prevent that?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think re not required, you can try `s.split()[-2]` where s is the string.

Comment: Do you just want the number at the end of string? `\d+$`?

Comment: the $ doesn't work since `r=str(sample_text)` makes the whole list into one string

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a string using `r=str(sample_text)` and now the string ends on `']`

Then there is only 1 end of string using `$` and you will get multiple matches as the lookahead is true at more positions. See the matches [here](https://regex101.com/r/s95DRa/1)

What you could do is for example join with a newline, use a capture group that will be returned by re.findall and use `re.M` for multiline.

```
\bHTTP/\d\.\d"\s\d+\s(\d+)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bHTTP/` Match `HTTP/`
- `\d\.\d"\s\d+\s` Match a digit `.` digit whitespace char 1+ digits and whitespace char
- `(\d+)` Capture 1+ digit in group 1
- `$` End of string

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zxBmt6/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/IScFog).

```
import re

sample_text = ['199.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/HTTP/1.0" 200 6245',
               'unicomp6.unicomp.net - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/HTTP/1.0" 200 3985',
               '199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/mission-sts-73.html HTTP/1.0" 200 4085',
               'burger.letters.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/liftoff.html HTTP/1.0" 304 0',
               '199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/sts-73-patch-small.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 4179']

def func():
    r = "\n".join(sample_text)
    regext = r'\bHTTP/\d\.\d"\s\d+\s(\d+)$'
    content_size = re.findall(regext, r, re.M)
    print(content_size)
func()
```

Output

```
['6245', '3985', '4085', '0', '4179']
```

Or using a list comprehension

```
def func():
    return [m.group(1) for m in (re.search(r'\bHTTP/\d\.\d"\s\d+\s(\d+)$', s) for s in sample_text) if m]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern: `(?<=HTTP\/[12]\.0\"\s)\d+\s(\d+)`

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` it is called positive [`look behind`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), it looks behind and checks if the pattern inside it is in behind of current position? if so then continue the matching (Note: it just check the pattern inside it not matching)
- `HTTP\/` match exactly HTTP/
- `[12]` match one of two these two digits (Note 2 is added for HTTP 2)
- `\.0\"` match with .0"
- `\s` match any white space
- `\d+` one or more digits (this part match with HTTP status code)
- `\s` white space
- `(\d+)` one or more digits and captured in a group

```
import re

pattern = "(?<=HTTP\/[12]\.0\"\s)\d+\s(\d+)"

text = """
'199.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/ 
 HTTP/1.0" 200 6245',
'unicomp6.unicomp.net - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/ 
HTTP/1.0" 200 3985',
'199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts- 
 73/mission-sts-73.html HTTP/1.0" 200 4085',
 'burger.letters.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400] "GET / 
shuttle/countdown/liftoff.html HTTP/1.0" 304 0',
 '199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/sts-73- 
patch-small.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 4179'
"""

print(re.findall(pattern, text))
```

```
Output:
['6245', '3985', '4085', '0', '4179']
```

Comment: So, how does he prevent the 200 from showing in his attempt at solving his homework problem?

Comment: His attempt to solve this problem with regex is wrong so I wrote a new pattern

Comment: Why is it wrong? He does not ask for someone to solve his homework, he asks why his solution is wrong and how to fix it. Presumably so he gets better at writing regexp. Providing a solution to the homework with no explanation does not answer the question and deprives him of that learning benefit.

Comment: Why is it wrong? try to run it and see why is it wrong. Can you fix the current regex? so write your answer.

Comment: BTW, I added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just split the strings and collect last element

```
sample_text = ['199.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245',
               'unicomp6.unicomp.net - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/ HTTP/1.0" 200 3985']

values = [entry.split()[-1] for entry in sample_text]
print(values)
```

output

```
['6245', '3985']
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about exactly what you want.

Currently your regex returns any number followed by a space `(\s\d+)` which are not followed by the exact sequence in your second group (which is all of them).

You want to write it like this: `\s(\d+)\n`

`\s`: match a space

`(\d+)`: match the number and return it

`\n`: make sure the line ends